# Does random forest account for temporal auto-correlation?

Tags: r, time-series, random-forest, autocorrelation, spatio-temporal

I have a dataset including several yearly time series of different sites. I have built multivariate random forest model in a leave-one-site out cross validation model using the `caret` package in R.

The model is doing well in predicting my dependent variable, however I am afraid that there is some temporal auto-correlation in my dataset. For the same site, one year influences the outcome of the other years, etc. Therefore, I am looking for a way to account for temporal auto-correlation in my model. I am aware of model such as ARMA model but was wondering if there is a way to do it for a random forest model.